# Qt setGeometry to negative value doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt

Im working with QT and I have a form with a QLabel in a QFrame. I want to set the QLabel's geometry so the bottom part of the QLabel is in the same place of the bottom of the frame. Since the label is longer than the frame, it's y coordinate should be negative.

```
int pos =  ui->imageFrame->height() - ui->imageLabel->pixmap()->height();
ui->imageLabel->setGeometry(0, pos, ui->imageFrame->width(), p.height());
```

Although when printing the QLabel's geometry, the y coordinate is correct, the label is showing on the upper part of the frame.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the label's alignment with `setAlignment`. Here's a working example:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

#include "MyWidget.h"

MyWidget::MyWidget()
{
  setFixedSize(200,200);
  QLabel *label = new QLabel;
  label->setPixmap(QPixmap("/some/image/file.jpg"));
  label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom);
  QHBoxLayout *hbox = new QHBoxLayout;
  hbox->addWidget(label);
  hbox->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
  setLayout(hbox);
}
```